# iAd banner ad is not working because of the following error (Sprite Kit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, iad

I am using sprite kit and I want the banner ad to display on all of my skscenes. I do not want to use self.candisplaybannerads because it pushes my scene up mid game and causes it to lead to a death in the game.

Here is the error: WARNING: More than 10 instances of ADBannerView or ADInterstitialView currently exist. This is a misuse of the iAd API, and ad performance will suffer as a result. This message is printed only once.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import iAd
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var AdBanner = ADBannerView()

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()

    /* Ad Banner Settings */
    AdBanner = ADBannerView()
    AdBanner.frame = CGRectZero
    AdBanner.delegate = self
    AdBanner.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    /* All iAd Functions */

    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        /* whatever you need */
        return true
    }

    func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        /* whatever you need */
    }

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        AdBanner.hidden = false
    }


    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        NSLog("Error Loading Ad")
        /* whatever you need */
        AdBanner.hidden = true
    }
    func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        /* whatever you need */
    }


    return true
}
```

Here is where I am calling the banner ad

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    appDelegate.AdBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-appDelegate.AdBanner.frame.size.height, appDelegate.AdBanner.frame.size.width, appDelegate.AdBanner.frame.size.height)
    self.view .addSubview(appDelegate.AdBanner)

    //authenticateLocalPlayer()

    if let scene = StartScreen(fileNamed:"StartScreen") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by using the automatic mode for banner ads. Just set 'canDisplayBannerAds' in your ViewController and Apple takes care about the number of instances:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

...
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In case you didn't know: The people who answers do that in their free time and the only motivation is to help. You answer could be considered as a little bit rude. BTW: I would not continue with iAD. It will be discontinued by Apple midth of 2016